# Using bin values and metadata in ChartElementFunction in histograms

Tags: bugs, histograms

The `DensityHistogram` command lets you specify a `ChartElementFunction` which according to the documentation:

> The arguments supplied to `ChartElementFunction` are the bin region
>   `{{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}}`, the bin values *lists*, and metadata `{m1,m2,...}`.

My question is how can I use the bin values lists and the metadata? When I try to access them all I get something like

```
System`DensityHistogramDump`thisBinList$270262
```

Comment: I think you're out of luck for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like the last two parameter sets that the documentation promises are passed to `ChartElementFunction` are actually passed. A test:

```
DensityHistogram[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 20], 
   ChartElementFunction -> Print];
```

> {{-2.,-1.},{-2.,-1.}}{}{}
>
> {{-1.,0.},{-2.,-1.}}{}{}
>
> {{-1.,0.},{-1.,0.}}{}{}
>
> {{-1.,0.},{0.,1.}}{}{}
>
> {{-1.,0.},{1.,2.}}{}{}
>
> {{0.,1.},{-2.,-1.}}{}{}
>
> {{0.,1.},{-1.,0.}}{}{}
>
> {{0.,1.},{0.,1.}}{}{}
>
> {{0.,1.},{1.,2.}}{}{}
>
> {{1.,2.},{2.,3.}}{}{}
>
> {{3.,4.},{1.,2.}}{}{}

The bin lists themselves can be obtained in two ways:

Firstly, from the internals of `DensityHistogram` using the height specification function (one possibility for the third argument):

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 20];

Reap[
  DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, ((Sow[{##}, bindata]; ##) &)], 
  bindata
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Secondly, using `HistogramList`:

```
HistogramList[data]
```

> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}}, {{0, 2, 1, 
>      0}, {1, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 3, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}}

As you can see, the bin boundary specification is written slightly different, but is in principle the same. The bin count lists are the same.